# Prevent foreach from loop html tag multiple time in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to loop data using foreach and I want to skip the html tag after the first item being looped.

I've tried like the code bellow, but the html tag `<p>` still being looped multiple time. What I want is the `<p>` tags only looped once

```
@foreach ($store_icon as $key => $icon)
   @if ($key < 1)
       <p class="available-at">Also available at:</p>
   @endif
   <a href="{{ $store->product_url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-right: 2px"></a>
@endforeach
```

Result example:

What I want is like this:

```
Also Available at
- Product 1
- Product 2
```

But using the code above it resulted like this:

```
Also Available at
- Product 1
Also Available at
- Product 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working, It must work and working the same code for as well, you can try --

```
@foreach ($store_icon as $key => $icon)
   @if ($key == 0)
       <p class="available-at">Also available at:</p>
   @endif
   <a href="{{ $store->product_url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-right: 2px"></a>
@endforeach
```

OR you can use like this

```
@if(!empty($store_icon))
<p class="available-at">Also available at:</p>
    @foreach ($store_icon as $key => $icon)
       <a href="{{ $store->product_url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-right: 2px"></a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: If i dump $icon it looks like this: https://pastebin.com/qzkiTqcx

Comment: Btw this is also doesn't work

Comment: I have updated my answers with other alternative. you can check the particular collection have data or not

Comment: Thanks! it working using the second answer

Answer (score 2):

Whats problem? Just take it out from loop.

```php
<p class="available-at">Also available at:</p>
@foreach ($store_icon as $key => $icon)
   <a href="{{ $store->product_url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-right: 2px"></a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I want to hide the tags if there's no data for looping

Comment: Use `@if (!$store_icon) <p class="available-at">Also available at:</p> @endif`